# c: typecast pointer to char to const char array

Tags: c, pointers, casting

this is the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void test_me(const char test_array[]){
        printf("%s\n", test_array);
        return;

}


void main(void){
        char *string = "Successfull cast!";
        const char test_array [100];
        /* 
         * something that fills the const char test_array
         * with the contend of *string
        */
        test_me(test_array);

}
```

The following I have tried yet:

```
strcpy(test_array, string); /*gcc: "...discards const qualifier..."*/
```

then this:

```
test_array[0] = string; /*gcc: "assignment of read-only location.."*/
```

...and some stuff that is hardly reasonable...

Someone suggests a solution?

EDIT: The point to this is, that the API of another module requests a `const char[]` as a parameter but I have the requested information exclusivly in the form of the pointer. So is there no way I can declare the test_array with the contend of *string? I know const is read-only but at some point a const must be declared ?

Comment: Remove const in decleration

Comment: @Fredrik: What's the problem using a string literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to skip the `const` keyword on the declaration. If you want to write to it then it clearly is not constant.

```
    char test_array[100];
```

Note that you can pass a non-const array to a function that want a `const` array, but not the other way around.

Comment: i made an edit to the question

Comment: Read the last segment of my answer. It is perfectly fine to pass a `char test_array[100]` to a function that wants a `const char test_array[]`.

Comment: though a workaround you solved my problem. thanks mr. Lindbäck!

Comment: It's not really a workaround - it is the way to do it. And you probably did it a hundred times before without even thinking about it. I'm talking about `strcpy` where the second parameter is `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

`const` in C means "read-only". Since you are attempting to perform writes, compiler rightly complains about it. If you intend to write into `test_array` (or modify it later) then there's no point in qualifying it with `const`.
So, just drop the `const` from: `const char test_array [100];`.

Regarding you edit:

> The point to this is, that the API of another module requests a const char[] as a parameter but I have the requested information exclusively in the form of the pointer.

You can always a `char*` to a function that expects `const char*` - which is allowed in C. The `const` in your API means it's saying that it's not intending to modify the contents of the pointer you pass it to. The answer is still the same: just drop the `const` from `const test_array[100];`

Also read this: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Comment: i made an edit to the question

Comment: @JoschKraus Your API definition doesn't stop you from passing `test_array` without making it `const`. It just means your API won't modify it.

Comment: Thank you @usr you solved this for me!

Comment: _`const` in C means "read-only"_ - No! It means "I, the programmer, guarantee to you , the compiler, I will not change the object after initialisation!"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a pointer to a function accepting an array.

In the context of a function declaration, a formal parameter of array types is treated as a pointer.

E.g.

```
void test_me(const char test_array[])
```

is interpreted as

```
void test_me(const char *test_array)
```

(see [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html))